# Panda CSS not generating create-recipe.mjs

Tags: reactjs, ark-ui, panda-css, park-ui

I've added PandaCSS, Ark and Park to a React project (following the steps at https://park-ui.com/docs/panda/overview/getting-started), and added a simple Heading component to test, but PandaCSS and it doesn't seem to be properly generating the create-recipe.mjs file -- I'm getting the following error when trying to use it (same error appeared with Accordion component, but thought I'd try simplifying things by just trying Heading to start):

```
[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve import "./create-recipe.mjs" from "styled-system/recipes/tooltip.mjs". Does the file exist?
.../cascata-sidebar/styled-system/recipes/tooltip.mjs:2:31
1  |  import { splitProps, getSlotCompoundVariant } from '../helpers.mjs';
2  |  import { createRecipe } from './create-recipe.mjs';
   |                                ^
3  |  
4  |  const tooltipDefaultVariants = {}
    at formatError (file://.../cascata-sidebar/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-wTaJK0Jt.js:63045:46)
    at TransformContext.error (file:///.../node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-wTaJK0Jt.js:63039:19)
    at normalizeUrl (file:///.../node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-wTaJK0Jt.js:61320:33)
    at async file:///.../node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-wTaJK0Jt.js:61470:47
    at async Promise.all (index 1)
    at async TransformContext.transform (file:///.../node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-wTaJK0Jt.js:61391:13)
    at async Object.transform (file:///.../node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-wTaJK0Jt.js:63340:30)
    at async loadAndTransform (file:///.../node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-wTaJK0Jt.js:49083:29)
    at async viteTransformMiddleware (file:///.../node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-wTaJK0Jt.js:58681:32
```

App.tsx

```
import { Heading } from './components/park/Heading'


function App() {

  return (
    <>
      <Heading>Hello</Heading>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Posted an [issue on the Park-UI Github](https://github.com/cschroeter/park-ui/issues/115) in case it's a bug; posting here in case it's me doing something silly :P

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how/why this happened, but removing the `styled-system` dir and regenerating seemed to fix it

```
$ rm -r styled-system/
$ npx panda codegen
```

I do have the prepare script set up in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "prepare": "panda codegen"
  },
```

Leaving this open in case there is some manual step needed in the docs to avoid this (or if there is some step that I just missed?)